# Decoding an ASN.1 DER OCTET STRING with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, x509, asn.1, der

Using the OpenSSL API, I have extracted a custom extension from a X.509v3 certificate with:

```c
X509_EXTENSION* ex = X509_get_ext(x509, 4);
```

The X509_EXTENSION object contains a value (ex->value) that is an ASN.1 OCTET STRING. The OCTET STRING contains a DER encoded UTF-8 string. I'm trying to decode the OCTET STRING to get the plain UTF-8 string.

I have tried a few things, such as:

```c
ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8(&buf, ex->value);
```

and

```c
M_ASN1_OCTET_STRING_print(bio, ex->value);
int len = BIO_read(bio, buf, buf_size);
buf[len] = '\0';
```

These both give me the DER encoded string. How do I get the plain UTF-8 string?

Comment: I used 'asn1_get_object' to do this a while ago, following the example in openssl code (around crypto/asn1/asn1_par.c:135). It's so painful to decode a big structure this way that I recommend to use an alternate asn1 parser such as SNACC or libtasn1.

Comment: @Francois: Thank you for the tip. Since I'm not trying to decode a big structure, just a single string, ASN1_get_object() might be adequate. However, I made an attempt at using it, based on how it's used in asn1_par.c, but couldn't get it working. Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: @Francois: I found out how to use the function and posted an answer based on that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Francois pointed me to the ASN1_get_object() function. That function is appropriate for this scenario where the certificate extension contains only a single value.

ASN1_get_object() takes a pointer to a pointer to a C buffer that contains a DER encoded object. It returns the data itself (by adjusting the pointer), the length of the data, the ASN.1 tag value and the ASN.1 object class.

```
ASN1_OCTET_STRING* octet_str = X509_EXTENSION_get_data(extension);
const unsigned char* octet_str_data = octet_str->data;
long xlen;
int tag, xclass;
int ret = ASN1_get_object(&octet_str_data, &xlen, &tag, &xclass, octet_str->length);
printf("value: %s\n", octet_str_data);
```

Comment: I was trying to do the exact same thing, but when applying your solution, I get the same string as before the call to ASN1_get_object function. Are you sure this function der decodes?

Comment: @Maggie: For the ASN.1 type that I was handling, `OCTET STRING`, it works. But it could be that it works because the only thing DER encoding does to an `OCTET STRING` is to wrap it up with a header. The bytes themselves stay the same. ASN1_get_object() does remove the header, but maybe that is *all* it does?

Comment: as I said, I am doing the EXACT same thing, ie. trying to get the human-readable value of the der-encoded certificate extension using openssl. the solution you provided does not work.

Comment: @Maggie: Is your certificate extension also an `OCTET STRING`?

Comment: Yes, the ASN.1 simple types are `BOOLEAN`, `INTEGER`, `BIT STRING`, `OCTET STRING`, `NULL`, `OBJECT IDENTIFIER`, `REAL`, `ENUMERATED` and `CHARACTER STRING`.

Comment: ok, how do I get data from X509 extension, except calling:
ASN1_OCTET_STRING* octet_str = X509_EXTENSION_get_data(extension);

Comment: It appears that you are seeking a general solution on how to extract the information in an x509v3 extension. As the title of this question states, it is only about the special case of decoding a single `OCTET STRING`. Beyond that, I can only point you to the original suggestion of @Francois, which is to use an external ASN.1 parser, such as SNACC or libtasn1 and to look at the OpenSSL source code (around crypto/asn1/asn1_par.c:135).

Comment: @RogerDahl Just so you're more fully informed, this appears to be runoff from a question posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012981/openssl-get-certificate-extensions). There's an open bounty, if you're interested in providing a more complete answer. :)

Comment: @MrGomez: Thanks for the link. Wild horses could not drag me back to the OpenSSL API :)